# Some windows aren't recognised by Unity

Tags: unity, window-manager, transmission, minimize

Some apps, including **Transmission** in particular, are not recognized by the Unity window manager.

- I am not able to focus or select certain windows.
- Curiously, I also can't drag it to the launcher.
- Opening works using the standard `Super > Type 'trans..' > Click`.

I'm not quite sure what I did to edit this behavior, if I did anything at all.

Note that running the command `unity --reset` does nothing for me.

*I've been having some problems with Unity (crashes and glitches, etc).*

Comment: I'm [unable to reproduce](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3296856/41823.ogv) this problem. Do you think you could record a screencast of it? [Desktop Recorder](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gtk-recordmydesktop) in the Ubuntu Software Center is handy for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unity in 11.04 has problems with windows that restore themselves from the notification area or from the messaging menu.

The simplest workaround is to maximize/unmaximize them or ALT+drag them to make their title bar visible again.

As I recall, the issue does not surface in 11.10 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

At least for Natty, Unity is buggy, and I have had frequent compiz crashes that are most easily fixed by a `compiz --replace` or reboot. if it is really bad I switch to a virtual terminal and`sudo reboot`. My best advice is to use Lucid or Oneiric Beta.

Answer (score -1):

Unity won't work well on hardware that is even 3 years old, that is what I have experiece recently, my solution was to "downgrade" to 10.10 Maverick Meerkat, You may, instead of downgrading, have to change which windows/file manager you are using, or you may have to go from the unity-3D to the Unity-2D, but i don't know what your uses for Ubuntu are, and if you want a bunch of flashy eye-candy, than the unity-2D WILL NOT be what you want!